# How to destroy multiple swipers JS on the page

Tags: javascript, arrays, swiper.js

Trying to destroy several swipers on the page,
but somehow the array I get in the destroy part (on the desktop width) is always empty.
the initialization on the resize to mobile works fine.
tried several ways? but the array always comes empty

```js
   var init = false;
    function swiperMode() {
        let mobile = 972;
        let allWorks = document.querySelectorAll('.work-item__images');
        let swiperArray = [];

        const buildSlider = (element, id) => {
            return new Swiper(element, {
                loop: true,
                observer: true,
                observeParents: true,
                slidesPerView: 2.5,
                spaceBetween: 16,
            });
        }

        // Enable (for mobile)

        
        console.log(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width);
        if(document.body.clientWidth <= mobile) {
            if (!init) {
                init = true;
                allWorks.forEach((item, id) => {
                    const slider = buildSlider(item, id);
                    swiperArray[id] = slider;
                    console.log(swiperArray);
                })
            }
        }
        console.log(swiperArray);
        if (document.body.clientWidth > mobile) {
            console.log(swiperArray, 2);
            if ( swiperArray.length === 0) return;
            for (let i = 0; i < swiperArray.length; i++) {
                console.log(swiperArray[i]);
                swiperArray[i].destroy(true, true);
            }
            swiperArray = [];            
            init = false;
        } 
        
    }

    /* On Load
    **************************************************************/
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        swiperMode();
    });

    /* On Resize
    **************************************************************/
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        swiperMode();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple

```js
var init = false;
function swiperMode() {
    let mobile = 972;
    let allWorks = document.querySelectorAll('.work-item__images');

    const buildSlider = (element, id) => {
        return new Swiper(element, {
            loop: true,
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            slidesPerView: 2.5,
            spaceBetween: 16,
        });
    }


    if(document.body.clientWidth <= mobile) {
        if (!init) {
            init = true;
            allWorks.forEach((item, id) => {
                const slider = buildSlider(item, id);
            })
        }
    }
    if (document.body.clientWidth > mobile) {
        allWorks.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item.swiper) item.swiper.destroy(true,true);
        })      
        init = false;
    }         
}

/* On Load
**************************************************************/
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    swiperMode();
});

/* On Resize
**************************************************************/
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    swiperMode();
});
```